# Optimización de consulta con Eloquent Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, querybuilder

Necesito una ayuda de alguno que pueda tenderme la mano amablemente, ya que necesito optimizar una consulta de laravel con **Eloquent** o **QueryBuilder**, para lo que pregunte lo intentaste si tanto que ya no supe que hace y deje el código como estaba. Aquí se los muestro. Dicha consulta hace que se cuelgue el servidor y tome picos muy altos de consumo, de antemano le agradecería su ayuda

```
$query = "SELECT a.id, cc.codigo, cc.nombre, a.unidad_medida_id, um.nombre as tipo_cambio, a.descripcion,
                        (SELECT count(adx1.id)
                            FROM `amortizacion` ax1
                                inner join  amortizacion_detalle adx1 on adx1.amortizacion_id = ax1.id
                            WHERE ax1.cliente_id=$cliente_id
                              and adx1.archivada = 0
                                and ax1.cuenta_corto_plazo=$cuenta_corto_plazo->cuenta_corto_plazo
                                and adx1.fecha_vencimiento > '$fecha_corte' and adx1.fecha_vencimiento <='$fecha_12_meses'
                        ) +  (SELECT count(adx1.id)
                            FROM `amortizacion` ax1
                                inner join  amortizacion_detalle adx1 on adx1.amortizacion_id = ax1.id
                            WHERE ax1.cliente_id=$cliente_id
                              and adx1.pago_monto = 0
                                and ax1.cuenta_corto_plazo=$cuenta_corto_plazo->cuenta_corto_plazo
                                and adx1.fecha_vencimiento <= '$fecha_corte'
                        ) AS cuotas,
                        b.nombre as banco,
                        t.nombre as tipo,
                        (SELECT sum(adx1.capital)
                            FROM `amortizacion` ax1
                            inner join  amortizacion_detalle adx1 on adx1.amortizacion_id = ax1.id
                            WHERE ax1.cliente_id=$cliente_id
                                and adx1.archivada = 0
                            and ax1.cuenta_corto_plazo=$cuenta_corto_plazo->cuenta_corto_plazo
                            and adx1.fecha_vencimiento > '$fecha_corte' and adx1.fecha_vencimiento <='$fecha_12_meses'
                        ) +  COALESCE((SELECT sum(adx1.capital)
                            FROM `amortizacion` ax1
                            inner join  amortizacion_detalle adx1 on adx1.amortizacion_id = ax1.id
                            WHERE ax1.cliente_id=$cliente_id
                              and adx1.pago_monto = 0
                            and ax1.cuenta_corto_plazo=$cuenta_corto_plazo->cuenta_corto_plazo
                           and adx1.fecha_vencimiento <= '$fecha_corte'
                        ),0) AS capital,
                        (SELECT sum(adx1.intereses)
                            FROM `amortizacion` ax1
                            inner join  amortizacion_detalle adx1 on adx1.amortizacion_id = ax1.id
                            WHERE ax1.cliente_id=$cliente_id
                               and adx1.archivada = 0
                            and ax1.cuenta_corto_plazo=$cuenta_corto_plazo->cuenta_corto_plazo
                            and adx1.fecha_vencimiento > '$fecha_corte' and adx1.fecha_vencimiento <='$fecha_12_meses'
                        ) +  COALESCE((SELECT sum(adx1.intereses)
                            FROM `amortizacion` ax1
                            inner join  amortizacion_detalle adx1 on adx1.amortizacion_id = ax1.id
                            WHERE ax1.cliente_id=$cliente_id
                            and ax1.cuenta_corto_plazo=$cuenta_corto_plazo->cuenta_corto_plazo
                            and adx1.pago_monto = 0
                            and adx1.fecha_vencimiento <= '$fecha_corte'
                        ),0) AS intereses,
                        (SELECT sum(adx1.iva)
                            FROM `amortizacion` ax1
                            inner join  amortizacion_detalle adx1 on adx1.amortizacion_id = ax1.id
                            WHERE ax1.cliente_id=$cliente_id
                              and adx1.archivada = 0
                            and ax1.cuenta_corto_plazo=$cuenta_corto_plazo->cuenta_corto_plazo
                            and adx1.fecha_vencimiento > '$fecha_corte' and adx1.fecha_vencimiento <='$fecha_12_meses'
                        ) + COALESCE((SELECT sum(adx1.iva)
                            FROM `amortizacion` ax1
                            inner join  amortizacion_detalle adx1 on adx1.amortizacion_id = ax1.id
                            WHERE ax1.cliente_id=$cliente_id
                               and adx1.pago_monto = 0
                            and ax1.cuenta_corto_plazo=$cuenta_corto_plazo->cuenta_corto_plazo
                            and adx1.fecha_vencimiento <= '$fecha_corte'
                        ),0) AS iva,
                        (SELECT sum(adx1.comision)
                            FROM `amortizacion` ax1
                            inner join  amortizacion_detalle adx1 on adx1.amortizacion_id = ax1.id
                            WHERE ax1.cliente_id=$cliente_id
                              and adx1.archivada = 0
                            and ax1.cuenta_corto_plazo=$cuenta_corto_plazo->cuenta_corto_plazo
                            and adx1.fecha_vencimiento > '$fecha_corte' and adx1.fecha_vencimiento <='$fecha_12_meses'
                        ) + COALESCE((SELECT sum(adx1.comision)
                            FROM `amortizacion` ax1
                            inner join  amortizacion_detalle adx1 on adx1.amortizacion_id = ax1.id
                            WHERE ax1.cliente_id=$cliente_id
                            and ax1.cuenta_corto_plazo=$cuenta_corto_plazo->cuenta_corto_plazo
                              and adx1.pago_monto = 0
                           and adx1.fecha_vencimiento <= '$fecha_corte'
                        ), 0)  AS comision,
                        (SELECT  sum(adx1.valor_cuota)
                            FROM `amortizacion` ax1
                            inner join  amortizacion_detalle adx1 on adx1.amortizacion_id = ax1.id
                            WHERE ax1.cliente_id=$cliente_id
                              and adx1.archivada = 0
                            and ax1.cuenta_corto_plazo=$cuenta_corto_plazo->cuenta_corto_plazo
                            and adx1.fecha_vencimiento > '$fecha_corte' and adx1.fecha_vencimiento <='$fecha_12_meses'
                        ) + COALESCE((SELECT  sum(adx1.valor_cuota)
                            FROM `amortizacion` ax1
                            inner join  amortizacion_detalle adx1 on adx1.amortizacion_id = ax1.id
                            WHERE ax1.cliente_id=$cliente_id
                            and ax1.cuenta_corto_plazo=$cuenta_corto_plazo->cuenta_corto_plazo
                            and adx1.pago_monto = 0
                           and adx1.fecha_vencimiento <= '$fecha_corte'
                        ),0) AS cuota_a_pago
                    FROM `amortizacion` a
                        INNER JOIN `amortizacion_detalle` ad ON ad.amortizacion_id = a.id
                        inner join entidads b on b.id = a.entidad_id
                        inner join tipo_operacions t on t.id = a.tipo_operacion_id
                        inner join unidad_medidas um on um.id = a.unidad_medida_id
                        inner join cuentas_contabilidad cc on cc.codigo=a.cuenta_corto_plazo and cc.cliente_id = a.cliente_id
                    WHERE a.cliente_id = $cliente_id
                        AND a.cuenta_corto_plazo = $cuenta_codigo
                    group by a.id, cc.codigo, cc.nombre, a.unidad_medida_id, um.nombre, a.descripcion";
        
            $encabezado = DB::select( DB::raw($query) );
```

Comment: Pero si la consulta tiene problemas de rendimiento entonces la optimización debe iniciar en la propia base de datos, por lo que veo que es mas un problema de SQL que de Laravel en si, recomiendo busques como obtener el plan de ejecución de la misma con *EXPLAIN* y añadas eso a tu pregunta, (*ojo eso es solo uno de los puntos a considerar*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira te pongo un ejemplo simple y adaptalo a lo tuyo, te recomiento que lo hagas por partes.

Creo una consulta y la guardo en una variable llamada $movimiento.

Luego la enlazo con la otra consulta asi:

> ->joinSub($movimiento, 'movimiento', function ($join) {
> $join->on('productos.id', '=', 'movimiento.producto_id');
> })

en joinSub le paso la consulta previa que hice aqui $movimiento, luego le pongo un alias a la tabla, le puse 'movimiento' para que todo este homogeneo y luego lo uno con la tabla que devolvera la respuesta final

```
$movimiento= Movimiento::
            where('anno', $year)
            ->groupBy('anno');




$productos = Producto::select(
            'productos.nombre AS producto',
            'productos.cantidad'
        )
            ->joinSub($movimiento, 'movimiento', function ($join) {
                $join->on('productos.id', '=', 'movimiento.producto_id');
            })
            ->orderBy('productos.nombre')
            ->get();
```